# When run by VS code, it cannot find the file while IDLE can run the same code with no problem, how to fix it?

Tags: python

when I try to run the code in vs code this is the error I get:

```
  File "c:\Users\liqin\Desktop\py\pygame\space invader\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    icon = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
PS C:\Users\liqin>
```

but when I used IDLE to run the same code it works
Is there some kind of setting I need to change in vs code to let it works properly?

(code and image are both in the same folder, not sure why vs code cant work)
[image: Inline image]

Comment: Try changing it from `alien.png` to the full path.

Comment: The working directory may not be identical to the directory the code file is in, so relative paths may fail. You can print the current directory with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: `os.getcwd()` will print the path where the file was called for execution. It does not necessarily print the path where the file is being executed is located. But in his case that should help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur when our image is not located by the program. Instead of writing alien.png, write the full path.